# Macro is working in Excel 2013 but gives compile error in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

My macro is working in Excel 2013 but gives a compile error in Excel 2016.

I know this is happening due to reference library issue.
The missing library is Microsoft Windows Common Controls- 2 6.0(SP6)

But I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You just need to add the library. In the "Tools" tab click "Reference" and look up the library. Check the box and click OK.